# Sorting a GridView Bound to a Dataset, DataTable null on cast?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This has been asked all over the place but I'm getting an issue I haven't seen anywhere else and I have no idea what's causing it or how to fix it.  The problem relates to sorting a GridView by column; code I've found online for the `Sorting` method hasn't worked.  Here is what I have:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Initial DataBind()
        BindGrid();
    }
    // Add dynamically created controls manually each time
    AddDropDowns();
}

protected void MainGrid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // This DataBind() may be redundant
    // Removing it didn't fix anything though.
    BindGrid();
    DataTable dataTable = MainGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
    // This block is never being entered, dataTable is always null
    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
        MainGrid.DataSource = dataView;
        MainGrid.DataBind();
    }            
}

public void BindGrid()
{
    // Prep the datasource for binding with fresh search results 
    BuildSearch();
    // And bind it
    MainGrid.DataSource = SearchResults.Products;
    MainGrid.DataBind();
}
```

The issue is that the block that does the actual sorting (indicated above) is never being entered, because `dataTable` is always null at that check.  I figured this would be because `MainGrid.DataSource` (which is a `DataSet`)  was null as well, but when I inspected it during debugging, much to my surprise`MainGrid.DataSource` was *not* null.  Why would casting it using `as` make `dataTable` null? And why didn't anyone else have this problem using this method? (I found this code on the asp.net forums in a near identical use-case)

I am very stumped on this, I feel like it should be so simple.  Any help is appreciated, including general ASP.net help, as I am a very new with the framework.  If anyone needs more info/code, let me know and I'm happy to update the post.

**EDIT: SOLVED**: To fix this issue, I switched implementations from a DataSet to a DataTable, the code looks almost exactly the same, it's declarations elsewhere in the project that change.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to find from the code snippet why it is NULL, as per my knowledge
but i can give u idea, at the time you bind your data table gridview, put the data table in view state or in session better to put in viewstate, and then retrieve data table at the time of sorting

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless. ASP.NET just adds an abstraction to make it look stateful.

When the postback comes - the old grid and datatable/dataset objects are gone. This is a fresh request, on a fresh thread with a fresh page object.

The grid maintains it's internal state via it's own internal datastructure (and some viewstate wiring...) - it will never be the same datatable on postback or even *a* datatable.

For your current approach to work, you need to re-fetch the datatable which needs sorting, either from the DB / code where you build it from scratch or from a cache(if it's *tiny*, maybe even the session / viewstate?)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and I think you're right that the source of my problem involves this, but the first thing the `Sorting` event does is rebind the GridView with `BindGrid()`.  Is that not sufficient to repopulate the GridView for sorting?